# Is it grammatically correct to use the definite article before "grana" in this case?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Stroma: the fluid surrounding grana, where the light-independent reactions occur.

In this vocabulary list entry—"Stroma: the fluid in the chloroplast surrounding the grana, where the light-independent reactions occur"—the definite article is needed, because it implies that the grana (plural for granum) are inside of the chloroplast.

However, should "the" be used before "grana" in the entry at the top? Since the chloroplast is not mentioned, it does not suggest that the grana are inside it. I am also not referring to a specific set of grana, as the number likely varies between chloroplasts. To my understanding, unlike the chromosomes, it is not essential that there must be a certain number of grana in the chloroplast of a species' individuals.

This question relates to this question: [Why is using the definite article “the” before a plural countable noun correct in this case when I have not mentioned the plural noun before?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/565904/why-is-using-the-definite-article-the-before-a-plural-countable-noun-correct-i)

Comment: Is there ever a case where grana can be observed without being surrounded by stroma?

Comment: I guess you could break the cell apart and observe the grana without it being in the stroma. However, I don't know how you would do that without turning the grana into mush mixed with other cellular components.

Comment: You are obviously discussing the internal structures of a cell. Not a specific cell but an archetypal one representing all cells or, at least, all cells of a particular type. In a case like that I would use the definite article as you are referring to "the" grana of that archetypal cell. It's a bit like saying "When building a house _the_ bricks must be held together by mortar".

Comment: Having *the grana* may help readers since saying "the stroma is the fluid surrounding grana" might be misread by some as "the stroma is the type of grana which surrounds fluid" rather than "the stroma is the fluid which surrounds the grana"

Comment: Could it be said without "the" as just "grana"? Yes, and the gist wouldn't change. Is it *wrong* to use "the" before "grana" in that context? No. Using "the" simply defines and determines that it's that grana, the grana that the aforementioned fluid in the aforementioned chloroplast surrounds. To use @BoldBen's example, you may say, "When building a house, *the* bricks must be held together by mortar," but you can also omit "the" and say, "When building a house, bricks must be held together by mortar." The meaning shifts slightly, but not crucially, while the gist and the crux is the same.